# my MainActivity restarts when calling onStartActivity for a pop up activity but only the first time

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a pop up activity that I created that gets called by a button press in a fragment.  When I press it, it restarts the MainActivity, but only on the first time we press the button.  After that it works normally.

This is the fragment's onCreateView

```
ImageButton profileButton = (ImageButton) 
rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_button);

profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("currentUser", "true");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Edit: I was actually able to figure it out on my own.  I had my MainActivity's launchmode be SingleInstance and when I changed it to SingleTask it worked.

Comment: What do you mean works normally? So the pop up is only show once per user?

Comment: please post whole code what you are doing.. Snippet does not help

Comment: The popup is supposed to show up any time the user presses the button.  However the first time the user pressed the button, MainActivity would close, restart and then open again.  If you then tried to press a button, it would open the popup activity without restarting and was acting how I expected it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to figure it out on my own. I had my MainActivity's launchmode be SingleInstance and when I changed it to SingleTask it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You must actually close your main activity programmatically after your intent so I would use the What about the Activity.finish() where activity is the name of your main activity. If you need further clarity just google the activity.finish() method its quite straightforward

Comment: MainActivity was not supposed to close.  It was supposed to remain open in the background of the popup activity.  The popup activity is set to only take a part of the screen and you can see MainActivity behind it.